# Multiple vulnerabilities have been reported in PHP

Tags: php

I am managing all PHP projects in my company. I got a report from security saying

> 1. PHP _php_stream_scandir() function- Arbitrary Code  execution
>      Vulnerability (CVE-2012-2688)
>      The vulnerability is caused by an error in the _php_stream_scandir()
>      function , which resides in 'main/streams/streams.c'. An attacker can
>      trigger an overflow in the _php_stream_scandir() function to execute
>      arbitrary code.
> 2. PHP SQLite- Bypass Restrictions Vulnerability (CVE-2012-3365) 
>      This vulnerability is caused by an error in SQLite to bypass open_basedir
>      protection mechanism, which could be exploited by remote attackers to
>      crash a vulnerable server, creating a denial of service condition.
>      Note: This vulnerability does not affect PHP versions 5.4.x

So they are telling us to upgrade all systems to 5.4.5. Does the above points effects projects too much or should is it fine to continue. Because i did not get to understand about the vulnerabilities they are talking about.

Comment: If you don't use `scandir`, there's probably not much to worry about regarding the first one. http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/54638 doesn't list PHP < 5.3.10 as vulnerable, either, so maybe those versons aren't.

Comment: @arxanas: it does list PHP < 5.3.10, only in some randomly sorted manner. According to PHP's own changelog and [NIST](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2012-3365), 5.3.15+ is not vulnerable - upgrading to that might be easier than to 5.4.

Comment: not personally using scandir() doesn't mean much, if you're using a library which does. You need to audit your projects' entire codebases to make sure it's not used anywhere.

Comment: @MarcB It also appears though, that the `scandir` has to incorporate user input, which is presumably less likely to evade one's notice. In any case, I don't know what the vulnerability actually is, so it is hard to say how to avoid it.

Comment: Which version are you using now?